# What's the difference between Dedicated Server and Root Server?

Tags: hosting, dedicated-server

This question has been asked before, but I don't get the answer clear enough so I ask it again.

What's the difference between Dedicated Server and Root Server?

People are talking about Root Server that you can manage it much more than dedicated server. Does it mean that the both of services are similar, but you likely work alone on Root Server like installing Operating System etc yourself?

Is there something that I should know about? Both of the systems can run remote desktop and such?

Comment: are you sure you are asking about the DNS? The answer you have accepted has nothing to do with it. Check tagging!

Comment: I have checked tagging and I'm aware of that tag and I'm aware that the tag isn't correct, but it sucks that the system doesn't accept any of the tags, because they require reputation. It forces me to use any tag in order to post the question. This is ridiculous stupid, because all tags which are correct to the question requires 300 reputation. Edit: As we see. Hardware was only one I were able to use. Dedicated, Server, Managed, Unmanaged all of those requires 300 reputation and this is the reason why question tags may be misleading.

Comment: "root server" is just marketing speak. It could mean anything.

Comment: Ah, I did not know what use of tags for you was limited. I replaced your tag with more appropriate ones.

Comment: Closed because BS reason.  Not everyone who has a server hosted does so in a "business environment".  I do have a dedicated server, and I don't run a business.  So... no place for us, right?  Who needs us plebs anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dedicated == dedicated hardware, you have full control over what OS is used and how it is configured.

Root == some server that you have root access on. You don't necessarily have full control over what OS is running.

I don't care for the term "root server", though. You typically only hear beginners using the term. There are more precise terms that should be used when referring to servers, virtual machine, for instance.

Comment: Then the companies offering them are beginners.  Obviously.

Answer (score -2):

I believe a root server is a server where you have root access (full privileges) to it, and a dedicated server is a physical server with hardware that is exclusively for your use.

I've yet to personally experience a dedicated server provider that didn't provide root access (either by default, or on request). I suspect they're just using slightly different terminology.